# Restriction on domain when using socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

I am using socket.io to establish 2 way communication between the server and the client.

Everything works fine, but it seems that if random person copies all my client side codes (including establishing connection) and make a separate new webpage, it seems that users who are connected to that new page can still communicate with my server. Which I think it can be used in bad ways.

Is there anyway that I can check where the socket messages are coming from? 'where' means the domain that user has used to send message to the server?

Is there a way to restrict or control list of domains to send and receive socket message?

Comment: Looks like this question's [been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729627/socket-io-security-maybe-allow-only-from-specific-domain) but it's perhaps not the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

According to [socket.io wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO), it is possible to specify 'origins' or clients' domain.

> **origins** defaults to `*:*`
>
> The origins that are allowed to connect to the Socket.IO server.